# Yup: how to get error message after failed cast?

Tags: javascript, validation, casting, joi, yup

I'm using `yup` for validation and there's this amazing [cast](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedcastvalue-any-options---any) method that I would like to try, however it is not clear from the documentation, how do I get the error message in case of failure? `cast` either transforms and validates and returns the result or returns `null` and that's it. That's not acceptable - I also require an error message. At the same time I wouldn't want to run it twice, like - once for validation, once for cast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> cast either transforms and validates and returns the result or returns null and that's it

`cast` ***DOES NOT*** `validate` the result - it simply transforms it. `validate(Sync)/isValid(Sync)` casts and then validates.

If you want to provide an error message on a specific schema in case of failed cast you do it with [typeError](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtypeerrormessage-string-schema)

> At the same time I wouldn't want to run it twice, like - once for validation, once for cast.

As I said, the validate methods always run casting first before validating (if cast fails, then it doesn't run validation). If you want cast and validation functionality, then you just call the validation methods and it returns the `cast` result (if valid) - you don't need to call `cast` unless you ONLY want to cast (without validating).

Comment: I had the impression that it casts internally to validate, but in the end if validation passes returns original value rather than casted one. Do you say that it will return casted one?

Comment: @jayarjo `Returns the value (a cast value if isStrict is false) if the value is valid, and returns the errors otherwise.` [yup readme](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedvalidatevalue-any-options-object-promiseany-validationerror)

Answer (score 1):

You can throw **Validation Error** anytime you want.

Here is my full implementation:

```
phone: yup
.string()
// .test('is-valid', 'phone.invalid', async (value) => {
//   if (typeof value === 'string') {
//     const number = phoneUtil.parseAndKeepRawInput(value, 'TR');
//     return phoneUtil.isValidNumber(number);
//   }
//   return false;
// })
.transform((value) => {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    const number = phoneUtil.parse(value, 'TR');
    if (phoneUtil.isValidNumber(number)) {
      return phoneUtil.format(number, PhoneNumberFormat.E164);
    }
  }
  throw new ValidationError(
    new ValidationError('phone.invalid', value, 'phone', 'is-valid')
  );
})
.required()
.nullable(false),
```

- Commented section is unnecessary and replaced in transform
- The reason behind throwing nested Validation Error is completely because of my error parsing logic.